# Why the weighted average get unintended result?

Tags: numpy, weighted-average

we know the `weighted average` formula is:
[image]

so, when I use numpy:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

wts = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(np.average(a, weights=wts))
```

it should be:

```
np.sum([1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4]) / 4   # 7.5
```

but why get `3.0`?

Comment: The denominator of the weighted average formula should be the sum of the weights so that the average of any constant equals that constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc of `average`, the average is

`avg = sum(a * weights) / sum(weights)`

If you want to divide by the number of weights instead of the summation, you can simply do

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
wts = np.array([1,2,3,4])

np.dot(a,wts) / wts.shape[0]
```